# Python Beautiful Soup - Getting past Steam's age check

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I'm learning web scraping and I've been trying to write a program that extracts information from [Steam's website](http://store.steampowered.com/) as an exercise.

I want to write a program that just visits the page of each top 10 best selling game and extracts something, but my program just gets redirected to the age check page when it tries to visit M rated games.

My program looks something like this:

```
front_page = urlopen('http://store.steampowered.com/').read()
bs = BeautifulSoup(front_page, 'html.parser')
top_sellers = bs.select('#tab_topsellers_content a.tab_item_overlay')

for item in top_sellers:
    game_page = urlopen(item.get('href'))
    bs = BeautifulSoup(game_page.read(), 'html.parser')
    #Now I'm on the age check page :(
```

I don't know how to get past the age check, I've tried filling out the age check by sending a POST request to it like this:

```
post_params = urlencode({'ageDay': '1', 'ageMonth': 'January', 'ageYear': '1988', 'snr': '1_agecheck_agecheck__age-gate'}).encode('utf-8')
page = urlopen(agecheckurl, post_params)
```

But it dosn't work, I'm still on the age check page. Anyone that can help me out here, how can I get past it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, seems like Steam use cookies to save the age check result. It's using `birthtime`.

Since I don't know how to set cookies use `urllib`, here is an example using `requests`:

```
import requests
cookies = {'birthtime': '568022401'}
r = requests.get('http://store.steampowered.com/', cookies=cookies)
```

Now there is no age check.

Comment: Thanks. However, for some games (like [PST: EE](http://store.steampowered.com/app/466300/Planescape_Torment_Enhanced_Edition/) for instance) there is an extra confirmation screen. To get through that, here are my cookies: `cookies = { 'birthtime': '283993201', 'mature_content': '1' }`.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Selenium Webdriver for form input, since it's an easy solution for clicks and keystrokes. You can look at the docs or checkout the examples here, on "Filling out and Submitting Forms".

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/